# Visual Studio 2015 cordova tools - enable rotation on ios devices - Cordova-Orientation-Lock plugin build error

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Visual studio 2015 cordova project - ios platform - I am using https://github.com/alexwasner/Cordova-Orientation-Lock cordova plugin to enable rotation on ios devices. Following instructions on the plugin page, I have modified MainViewController.h and MainViewController.m (these files are part of the ios platform.)

So I assume the bundle passed from visual studio for the mac to compile will contain the modified files. But once unbundled on the mac, MainViewController.h and MainViewController.m have no changes on them - they are the original ones. Is visual studio putting a cached version of the files on the bundle?

Cleared Cordova cache and rebuilt - no luck. Tried and include the 2 files on vs project to see if changes would be detected and passed - no luck. Also tried and include entries for the 2 files on changeList.json - they are removed upon compilation.

I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to figure it out, switched to the more popular http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation to allow ios rotation - working just fine, no .h/.m tinkering required

```
angular.module('main.module', [deps here])
    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if (window.screen) {
                // allow user rotate
                screen.unlockOrientation();
            }
        });
    })
```